# C# cannot convert anonymous method to type int because it's not a delegate type

Tags: c#, anonymous-function

I'm trying to use an anonymous method in a reg replace to convert each character to the next letter of the alpahbet.  I'm getting the error "cannot convert anonymous method to type int because it's not a delegate type".  Below is the code.

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace LetterChange
{
 class Program
 {
    public static string LetterChanged(string str) {
        string changed = null;

        changed = Regex.Replace(str, @"[a-zA-z]", 
            delegate(char c) { if (c == 'z' || c == 'Z') return 'A'; else   convert.ToChar(Convert.ToInt32(c));});
        return changed;
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Console.WriteLine(LetterChanged("hello*3"));
        Console.Read();
    }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Replace` method takes a `MatchEvaluator`:

```
 string MatchEvaluator(Match match)
```

So it takes a `Match` which has a `Value` property representing the matched string, and returns a string:

```
var changed = Regex.Replace(str, @"[a-zA-z]",
    delegate (Match c) {
        if (c.Value == "z" || c.Value == "Z")
        {
            return "A";
        }
        else
        {
            return Convert.ToChar(Convert.ToInt32(c)).ToString();
        }
    });
```

Also I would use a lambda to infer the parameter type instead of having to write the type, the `delegate` syntax is not recommended anymore :

```
var changed = Regex.Replace(str, @"[a-zA-z]", c => { … });
```

Answer (score 0):

Your match evaluator delegate does not match [`MatchEvaluator`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.matchevaluator(v=vs.110).aspx) signature expected by [`Regex.Replace`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ht1sxswy(v=vs.110).aspx). This will compile:

```
return Regex.Replace(
    str
,  @"[a-zA-z]"
,  delegate(Match m) {
       int pos = char.ToUpper(m.Value[0]) - 'A';
       pos = (pos+1) % 26; // Use % for wrapping around
       return ((char)('A'+pos)).ToString();
   }
);
```

However, this is one of the situations where using regex makes things *less* clear. A simple loop modifying characters one-by-one in a character array or a string builder would be a more readable alternative:

```
char[] txt = str.ToCharArray();
for (int i = 0 ; i != txt.Length ; i++) {
    char c = char.ToUpper(txt[i]);
    if (c < 'A' || c > 'Z') continue;
    int pos = (c - 'A' + 1) % 26;
    txt[i] = (char)('A' + pos);
}
str = new string(txt);
```